# Selecting string columns in pandas df (equivalent to df.select_dtypes)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a Pandas `df` with different data types, `df.select_dtypes` can be very useful to keep only desired columns or to get rid of unwanted columns for a particular application.

However, there seems to be no way of addressing `string` dtypes using this method.

From [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) (emphasis mine):

> ValueError
>     If both of include and exclude are empty
>     If include and exclude have overlapping elements
>     **If any kind of string dtype is passed in.**

and

> To select strings you must use the object dtype, but note that this will return **all** object dtype columns

Indeed, using `df.select_dtypes(exclude=['str'])` raises an error (although it is a `TypeError` and not a `ValueError` as the docs claim) and using `df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])` removes all `object` columns, not just `string` columns.

Given a `df` like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'int_col':[0,1,2,3,4],
                   'dict_col':[dict() for i in range(5)],
                   'str_col':list('abcde')})
```

and considering that

```
df.dtypes
```

is `object` for both `str_col` and `dict_col`:

**What is the best way of excluding or including all string columns?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Option 1**

Using `df.applymap` and `type`, and equating to `str`:

```
In [377]: (df.applymap(type) == str).all(0)
Out[377]: 
dict_col    False
int_col     False
str_col      True
dtype: bool
```

Each element in each column converted to its type and then equated to `str`. After that, just call `.all(0)` or `.min(0)` to get a per-column verdict.

---

**Option 2**

Using `df.applymap` and `isinstance`:

```
In [342]: df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)).all(0)
Out[342]: 
dict_col    False
int_col     False
str_col      True
```

---

To include these string columns, you can boolean index on the columns:

```
idx = ... # one of the two methods above
df_new = df[df.columns[idx]]
```

Exclusion would be

```
df_new = df[df.columns[~idx]]
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! For completeness' sake: actual inclusion or exclusion of string columns could then be done with `df.loc[:,(df.applymap(type)==str).all(0)]` and `df.loc[:,(df.applymap(type)!=str).all(0)]`, respectively.

Comment: @WhoIsJack That, or index on columns (added to my answer).

Answer (score 1):

From the pandas source:

```
~/.local/share/virtualenvs/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py in invalidate_string_dtypes(dtype_set)
    851     non_string_dtypes = dtype_set - {np.dtype("S").type, np.dtype("<U").type}
    852     if non_string_dtypes != dtype_set:
--> 853         raise TypeError("string dtypes are not allowed, use 'object' instead")
    854 
    855
```

best practice is to use `object` instead, apparently. So, just do

`df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])`

under the assumption that no actual Python objects are in those columns but `str` types.